# How to efficiently find multiple relationship size

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have a large graph (over 1 billion edges) that has multiple relationship types between nodes.
In order to check the number of nodes that have a single unique relationship between nodes (i.e. a single relationship between two nodes per type, which otherwise would not be connected) we are running the following query:

```
MATCH (n)-[:REL_TYPE]-(m) 
WHERE size((n)-[]-(m))=1 AND id(n)>id(m)
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT n) + COUNT(DISTINCT m)
```

To demonstrate a similar result, the below sample code can run on the `movie graph` after running
`:play movies` in an empty graph, resulting with 4 nodes (in this case we are asking for nodes with 3 types of relationships)

```
MATCH (n)-[]-(m) 
WHERE size((n)-[]-(m))=3 AND id(n)>id(m)
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT n) + COUNT(DISTINCT m)
```

Is there a better/more efficient way to query the graph?

Comment: If you can give for granted the direction of the relationship on the query it surely helps

Comment: Also tipicaly the "distinct" is a performance bottleneck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query is more performant, since it only scans each relationship once [whereas `size((n)--(m))` will cause relationships to be scanned multiple times]. It also specifies a relationship direction to filter out half of the relationship scans, and to avoid the need for comparing native IDs.

```
MATCH (n)-->(m)
WITH n, m, COUNT(*) AS cnt
WHERE cnt = 3
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT n) + COUNT(DISTINCT m)
```

*NOTE: It is not clear what you are using the `COUNT(DISTINCT n) + COUNT(DISTINCT m)` result for, but be aware that it is possible for some nodes to be counted twice after the addition.*

[UPDATE]

If you want to get the actual number of distinct nodes that pass your filter, here is one way to do that:

```
MATCH (n)-->(m)
WITH n, m, COUNT(*) AS cnt
WHERE cnt = 3
WITH COLLECT(n) + COLLECT(m) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes AS node
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT node)
```

Comment: The `COUNT(DISTINCT N)`  is to show how many nodes are involved in these relationship .if we wanted to count the number of relationships - what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: See my updated answer for one way to get a reliable count of distinct nodes that pass your filter.

Comment: using the above answer we are not getting correct results

Comment: Thx for the answer - i'll open a followup question

Comment: Here is the [followup question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58622363/match-single-relationship)