# Match single relationship

Tags: cypher

This is a follow up question to [How to efficiently find multiple relationship size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608243/how-to-efficiently-find-multiple-relationship-size)

Assuming working with the [movie sample graph](https://neo4j.com/developer/example-project/)
When running the below query
`MATCH ()-[:PRODUCED]-() RETURN count(*)`
we know that there are 15 `PRODUCED` relationships.
From the query

```
MATCH (n)-->(m)
WITH n,m, COUNT(*) as cnt
WHERE cnt=3 RETURN *
```

We know there are 2 `PRODUCED` relationships that connect 2 nodes with additional relationships.

How can we find the relationships that are distinct relationships between nodes (i.e. there are no additional relationships except for the `PRODUCED` relationship)?

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was using this query

```
MATCH p=(n)-[:PRODUCED]->(m)
WHERE size((n)--(m))=1
RETURN count(p)
```

which results with 9 (total is 15, with size=3 is 2, and size=2 is 4)